Charging file (and, font) display direction and start position across horizontal lines
I have seen a programmer post a picture of how in an IDE the left window had code displayed left to right and the right window had the code displayed right to left, and both were bound.
I have posted a picture.

In the above two Vim windows, the user writes the C code:
int
hey;

issues commands such as
(First window in picture)

:vsplit;
...enter bind mode ex command here so that when the cursor scrolls in the left window the cursor scrolls simultaneously in the right window. If the windows are of different widths, some code in the Vim source code is needed, in a way that the binding takes care of respecting the different window widths properly
...enter ex command to display the file in right to left horizontal line displayal mode in the right window (this sets the start display position of the text in each line to the rightmost position and adds each character displayed to the left of the previous one)

(Second window in picture)
The font rendering is actually subject to each font character being displayed with a flip along a vertical axis through it.

: flipfont flipaxis=vertical, issued for the second window

Maybe Vim has access in it's API code to some sort of text rendering code. If not, then perhaps the API needs to implement some modification to support this in those terminals where it can be supported.
I have described the sort of ex commands I am looking for to achieve these behaviors.
Are they implemented?
If yes, what are the exact ex commands I must issue in vim to obtain these behaviors?
When will this be implemented?
I am looking forward to seeing this.
This means I can display my left to right language or right to left language as I please.
It would be beneficial.
Also to newbies and mind-flexible -oriented individuals/thinkers.
EDIT: The solution to the first problem has been provided in an answer. As to the second problem, I was not looking for Unicode support for the reflected charcters. I was just looking for displayal support via an ex command. This could also be set in the ~/.vimrc file if someone really wanted it.
However, it is possible that the Unicode consortium may want to add support for reflected charcters, for instance, according to the eight elements of the dihedral group of order 8, for completeness (thus, not just vertical reflection), or, more generally, via the specification of an optional reflection and a rotation charcter. Both cases, described in this paragraph, could be supported via the insertion of special begin and end Unicode characters, which could also be parametrized (as described in this paragraph), for arbitrary text blocks (and, then, that would have to be supported in code).
Not sure if there are any plans to add support for such text transformation, in Unicode. If so, text editors could not just display the transformation but also store it in the file (and text renderers would have to render it).
However, this would be a third scenario, that goes beyond my original post. Not, sure, if, anyone, would implement, this (but, it could be useful, it could be helpful).
Thanks.

The second picture is not possible n Vim. Vim is a console oriented program that uses existing font. There are no mirror character for every character in Unicode fonts so I'm afraid what you are asking will remain impossible n Vim :-/

"It would be beneficial." - could you explain how? The benefit of picture 1 is obvious for people using right-to-left languages. I'm struggling to see how picture 2 would be.

But there must be a way to implement it. People with learning difficulties, people with dyslexia, connotations and transitioners from between left to right and right to left systems, as well as mine boggled tired or break needing people who might just want it need a different view of the text to relax or get intrigued would need such a thing, and it would be beneficial to them. Thanks.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Thinking about the whole thing again, I think the most promising way would be to use an external tool to swap pixels on the rendering level. Similar to the the magnifying glass tool, there may be utilities that can provide a mirror image effect. I don't think this is anything that should be built into Vim.

First Picture
The first picture is somehow possible in Vim:

set scrollbind
vsplit
set scrollbind
setlocal rightleft

Second Picture
The second picture is not possible in Vim. Vim is a console oriented program that uses existing font. There are no mirror character for every character in Unicode fonts so I'm afraid what you are asking will remain impossible n Vim :-/

There used to be bidi support (? help tbidi), but I thought someone told me recently it was unmaintained.

Thanks @D.BenKnoble have tested the termbidi option on Windows and seems to not have the symmetry effect on font. The documentation is a bit vague to me about the exact 'shaping' effect it is suppose to have. Do you know what it brought when it was maintained?

I do not; I'm also not certain it is unmaintained. There's still plenty of documentation on arabic and hebrew within Vim, so I'm not sure.

@VivianDeSmedt The 'shaping' referred to in :help tbidi is described in `:help 'arabicshape'. It's unrelated to the mirror image glyphs that the OP is looking for. See e.g. https://www.lebanesearabicinstitute.com/arabic-alphabet/#Arabic_Script for more details.

Interesting :-) Thanks Rich!

Thank you for your answer. Why isn't the second picture possible, and, how can it be implemented? What would need to change, in the code, to support it's implementation? Thanks.

Like drafted in the answer Vim doesn't draw the character it self. It uses existing fonts. It is the responsability of th OS to draw the character. I'm not aware of a way to draw the symmetric character and I doubt it exist (I could be wrong). If I'm right there are no ways to implement that without improving the OS.

So perhaps attention to this issue should go to the maintainers of the Linux kernel. Perhaps I will raise this issue on the Unix and Linux stack exchange thanks.

Meanwhile, I was unable to understand what the tbidi / termbidi options do. Can someone please explain it to me? Thanks.

Indeed that would be the right place. But maybe ellaborating more on why it would be useful would help to gain more traction (the mere mortal I'm face a lot of difficulty reading mirrored text :-)).
